# Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I publish my asp.net mvc 3 app in windows azure and when I go my site I see error "Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request." what does it mean?

Comment: You haven't presented enough information here for us to help you. I'm not familiar with Azure, but it's clear that you need to learn how to debug code deployed there.

Comment: This could be any number of things, as this is too-generic a question. We don't even know if your mvc app runs locally. We don't know if you tried taking an MVC app and adding it to a Windows Azure project, or if you started out with a Windows Azure project and added a new MVC project. Zero details? Zero answers.

Comment: I'll start all over again.
I have three ASP.NET MVC application with a database sql server 2008.
I have added to the project Windows Azure project. In The portal management Azure I created a database, user, password.
Question: What connection strings should I use to publish my application and it normal working?
Sorry for worse English.

Comment: I would suggest you to look "Guidelines for Connecting to SQL Azure Database" described in this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336282.aspx

Comment: One valid reason for this question is that the conventions in MVC hides the actual error, and displays a predefined error template instead. This isn't obvious, and require a certain knowledge of the framework to figure out. To anyone ending up here because of this, look at the global action filter HandleError in Global.asax.cs, the Shared View Error.cshtml and the web.config setting <customErrors>

Comment: I agree with Per-Frode Pedersen, rather than close this question, someone should have just explained to the OP how to get CustomErrors off so that he can see the actual error that is occurring. I two encountered this generic error template after deploying an MVC app and an answer to this would have saved me time. Thanks, Per-Frode Pedersen, for pointing me towards the solution. +1 to counter the downvote, and because I had the same question.

Comment: To get the actual error message rather than this custom one I had to do three things: 1) Compile my application with Debug configuration, rather than Release, and then deploy the application 2) Add  <customErrors mode="Off" /> to <system.web> in the _web.config_ file. 3) Restart the website in IIS Manager. After doing this I got the actual error message and could debug further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others suggested there could be scores of things went wrong which cause this problem. I would suggest you to read the suggestion given in the following post to start investigating your problem:

[Webrole is not starting and always busy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381345/webrole-is-not-starting-and-always-busy/10386637#10386637)

Here is the connection string you would need to add into web.config to connect SQL Azure DB from ASP.NET application

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="SQLAzureConnection" connectionString="Data Source=<ProvideServerName>.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=TestDb;User ID=<ProvideUserName>;Password=<ProvidePassword>;Encrypt=true;Trusted_Connection=false;"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I doubt it. I think that error message is coming from the MVC app, which means it's running.

Comment: I totally agree smarx. I just wanted to suggest that as role is already running you could RDP to instance (RDP should work in this situation) and look for event log for any possible exception or investigate what could be issue over there..