# Azure toolkit for windows phone publish issue

Tags: windows-phone-7, azure

I um using Windows Azure toolkit for Windows Phone from codeplex. After creating a Windows Phone Cloud Application from a template, I started it on localhost and it run succesfully. Then i followed instructions on Codeplex on how to deploy on Azure, and published it also succesfully - I got an url to the website, but after typing the url in browser the website didn't load, and after a while there was a timeout. I tried both production and staging deployment. Can't resolve why this happens - did anyone faced familiar problem?

The publish completed successfully however this application is not running properly on Windows Azure.

Comment: please suggest what kind WP7 application is it? You mentioned that you tested your application with Localhost however have you tested with Compute Emulator? This is done by setting your webrole app as startup project or manually launching the webrole app.

Comment: I tried with standard template 'Windows Phone Cloud Application' which comes with this toolkit [link](http://watwp.codeplex.com/) - without adding a single line of code. I ran the webrole app and tested with azure emulator - it worked ok.

Comment: May I ask what it your URL? Also have u have RDP access enabled with your app so you can login to Azure VM?

Comment: This is URL for the staging development: [link](http://42953797ca4a46e3a6ecf2f6e53eb954.cloudapp.net/) and this is URL for the production development: [link](http://diabetix.cloudapp.net/) (the same app). I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by RDP access to login to Azure VM - do you mean logging to Windows Azure Management Portal to see my developments?

Comment: Got it RDP to Azure VM is different then Login to Azure Mgmt Portal. When you publish your application you can setup RDP access to so that your can RDP to your Azure VM and investigate the problem. Here are the steps: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/04/03/setting-rdp-access-in-windows-azure-application-with-windows-azure-sdk-1-3-1-4.aspx

Comment: ok, now I'm logged via RDP to Azure VM - when I type in the browser http://<remote ip address v4>/default.aspx I get "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" message immediatelly. Is there any way to debug or sth remotely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using Web Role type WP7 Phone application look for all the steps suggested in the link below:

[Webrole is not starting and always busy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381345/webrole-is-not-starting-and-always-busy/10386637#10386637)

Also if you still could not find the root cause open a Windows Azure support ticket and you will get some help to find the root cause.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the problem was that the role actually started but web app crashed - in my webconfig file i had configured references to System.Web.WebPages & System.Web.Helpers both version 1.0.0.0, while in project reference was to version 2.0.0.0. Anyway still can't understand why in this case, web project ran properly on my localhost.

Comment: I am glad that your problem resolved. When u run application is local machine it is using your IIS which may have far different configuration then what you get on Azure VM and that is always a factor and in most case the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh134844.aspx

Remoting into the VM is a great way to see what is going on.  Does it come up if you want for a while (maybe 30 minutes)?