# Azure asp.net mvc 3 publishing/deployment issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure, azure-web-roles

Hi I have a MVC 3 web project which has been deployed to Azure successfully previously.
Since i had some problems with github,
and the Azure cloud project just won't publish, we have tried to delete/create new projects; updated varies settings, endpoints; include all of the dlls; tried to look for diagnostics.
even we tried to created a blank new projects and deployed it
so far nothing works

```
3:37:12 PM - Preparing deployment for Subscription with Subscription ID: 519e1c......
3:37:13 PM - Connecting...
3:37:14 PM - Verifying storage account 'blahblah'...
3:37:15 PM - Uploading Package...
3:37:45 PM - Creating...
3:39:53 PM - Created Deployment ID: 244f269afefe40fb99........
3:39:53 PM - Starting...
3:40:28 PM - Initializing...

3:40:28 PM - Instance 0 of role Web is in an unknown state
3:45:34 PM - Instance 0 of role Web is starting the virtual machine
3:46:42 PM - Instance 0 of role Web is in an unknown state
```

then busy, cycling.....

Comment: When your role us looping with "Busy > Starting > ....." it means your role host process is experiencing an exception in your Role code. Because of it the host process dies and the Azure App Agent restarts it again after some time.. your best bet is to follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381345/webrole-is-not-starting-and-always-busy/10386637#10386637

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see what is going on, just activate Remote Desktop on the instance.

I found that between recycling of the instance there is enough time to run the web site and get the yellow screen of death telling you which dll you are missing.